# How to resove the issue unable to resolve class XSSFWorkbook?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read the xlsx file using the below code but getting unable to result class.. any help would be appreciated...

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script7.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class XSSFWorkbook @ line 8, column 11. srcBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\PerTableData\\TestData-Mix.xlsx"))) ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable


import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
//import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter

//Create data formatter
//dFormatter = new DataFormatter()

//Create a new workbook using POI API
srcBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\PerTableData\\TestData-Mix.xlsx")))

//Create formula evaluator to handle formula cells
fEval = new XSSFFormulaEvaluator(srcBook)

//Get first sheet of the workbook (assumes data is on first sheet)
sourceSheet = srcBook.getSheetAt(0)

//Sets row counter to 0 (first row)-- if your sheet has headers, you can set this to 1
context.rowCounter = 0

//Read in the contents of the first row
sourceRow = sourceSheet.getRow(0)

//Step through cells in the row and populate property values-- note the extra work for numbers
elNameCell = sourceRow.getCell(0)
testCase.setPropertyValue("ElName",dFormatter.formatCellValue(elNameCell,fEval))

atNumCell = sourceRow.getCell(1)
testCase.setPropertyValue("AtNum",dFormatter.formatCellValue(atNumCell,fEval))

symbolCell = sourceRow.getCell(2)
testCase.setPropertyValue("Symbol",dFormatter.formatCellValue(symbolCell,fEval))

atWtCell = sourceRow.getCell(3)
testCase.setPropertyValue("AtWeight",dFormatter.formatCellValue(atWtCell,fEval))

boilCell = sourceRow.getCell(4)
testCase.setPropertyValue("BoilPoint",dFormatter.formatCellValue(boilCell,fEval))

//Rename request test steps for readability in the log; append the element name to the test step names
testCase.getTestStepAt(0).setName("GetAtomicNumber-" + testCase.getPropertyValue("AtNum"))
testCase.getTestStepAt(1).setName("GetAtomicWeight-" + testCase.getPropertyValue("AtWeight"))
testCase.getTestStepAt(2).setName("GetElementySymbol-" + testCase.getPropertyValue("Symbol"))

//Add references to sheet to re-use it in ReadNextLine step
context.srcWkSheet = sourceSheet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the import:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
                      ^^^^
```

you have only added:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
```

Comment: still facing issue "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook @ line 2, column 1. import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; ^"

Comment: Which version of apache-poi do have in your dependencies? Can you cow the build file?

Comment: poi-bin-3.10-FINAL-20140208.tar...there are 3 jar files dom4j-1.6.1, stax-api-1.0.1 and xmlbeans-2.3.0 i have placed in class path..

Comment: add `poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL.jar` or a later version to your classpath.

Comment: added this as well no luck still getting someerror about XSSF